# will phonebuild build cordova project causing malfunction?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-3

I am developing App by using cordova 3.1.0 , and want to make it public by using phonebuild to build my app for cross platform. The outcome is good, but is that any problem that I use `phonebuild` to build a `cordova`  project, as i know phonegap and cordova basically are the same except for package name. theoretically it will not be any problem.

I wanted to double confirm it , will the outcome same as I build locally using `cordova build` or is that anything I need to take note using phonebuild to build cordova apps

Answer (score 0):

You may encounter problem if you try to use plugins in your project.

Have a look at this post to have an idea of what may go wrong and how to solve it : [Phonegap Build Config.xml Malformed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21138074/phonegap-build-config-xml-malformed)