# Malformed config.xml when trying to compile with PhoneGap Build

Tags: xml, cordova

I am trying to build a PhoneGap project. This is my config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="org.coenraets.ionicdirectory" version="0.0.3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Movie Server</name>
    <description>
        Simple client to access my movie server.
    </description>
    <author email="benedict@ovalbit.com" href="http://ovalbit.com">
        Benedict Lewis
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144" />
</widget>
```

If I try to compile it using PhoneGap Build I get a malformed config.xml error. If I take out the icon lines then I have no problems building. I got the code from the docs so I'm really not sure what the problem can be.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Phonegap Build Config.xml Malformed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21138074/phonegap-build-config-xml-malformed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
<widget id="org.coenraets.ionicdirectory" version="0.0.3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

to:

```
<widget id="org.coenraets.ionicdirectory" version="0.0.3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
```

Notice that the xml name space in the one you have is for Cordova, not phonegap. Even though they are technically interchangeable, for the use of `gap:platform` you need to use the `xmlns:gap` name space.